# Joining two select statements into one with 2 WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm using these two select statements and want to join them into just one. Does anyone have any suggestions. However, the problem is that I'm using access and the case clause isn't there in access.

```
SELECT 
     Table_1.Table_Identification_Number,
     AVG (Table_2.Coulmn-2) AS avg_attribute
FROM 
    Table_1 JOIN
    Table_2 ON Table_1.Table_Identification_Number = Table_2.Table_Identification_Number
WHERE
    Table_2.Column-3='1'
GROUP BY 
    Table_1.Table_Identification_Number


SELECT 
     Table_1.Table_Identification_Number,
     AVG (Table_2.Coulmn-2) AS avg_attribute
FROM 
    Table_1 JOIN
    Table_2 ON Table_1.Table_Identification_Number = Table_2.Table_Identification_Number
WHERE
    Table_2.Column-3='2'
GROUP BY 
    Table_1.Table_Identification_Number
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also, fix the database tags to be sure your database is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want conditional aggregation.  If so, you can express this in MS Access as:

```
SELECT t1.Table_Identification_Number,
       AVG(IIF(t2.Column_3 = 1, t2.Column_2, NULL)) as avg_1,
       AVG(IIF(t2.Column_3 = 2, t2.Column_2, NULL)) as avg_2
FROM Table_1 as t1 JOIN
     Table_2 as t2
     ON t1.Table_Identification_Number = t2.Table_Identification_Number
WHERE t2.Column_3 IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY t1.Table_Identification_Number;
```